# Class 'App\File' not found in laravel-5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

when I load my app then at /file page it gives the error:

> **Class 'App\File'** not found.

it is giving the error at this line:

```
$files = File::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(30);
```

this is the complete code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\File;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $files = File::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(30);

        return view('file.index', ['files' => $files]);
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: do you have model Named as `File.php` in `Project\app` folder if yes share the Model file too

Comment: Please check that a model named `File` exists.

Comment: @Manojkiran.A   i have model File.php in \app:<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UploadedFile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
     'filename'
    ];
}

Comment: @DhananjayKyada yes::<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UploadedFile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
     'filename'
    ];
}

Comment: please add your entire model code in your question not in the comment part

Comment: @programmer0001 Replace `File` with `UploadedFile` in your controller. Also, the model name and file name should be the same.

Comment: this is complete structure   https://ibb.co/ts5sg6s

Comment: @DhananjayKyada thnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `namespace`. Go inside `File` modal and check what is the namespace there and use the same namespace followed by the class name.

For example: 
If your `File.php` modal is inside `app/Models` folder and name space is like this

In `File.php`

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Then in your controller use it like this

```
use App\Models\File;
```

Comment: Thats fine. Open your `File.php` check what is the `namespace`  its using. Use that namespace in the controller followed by the class name.. And if that doesn't work. Try `composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 0):

> Hi can you please verify that the namespace on top of File.php model
>   is namespace App;?
>
> Something like:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;`
use Illuminate\Notifications\MustVerifyEmail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\UploadedFile; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage; 


class FileController extends Controller
{

public function index() 
{ 
    $files = UploadedFile::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(30); 
    return view('file.index', ['files' => $files]); 
}
```

You should keep the model name and file name same. In your case both are not same.

Answer (score 0):

Make an alias of the File model namespace first then try again. For example

```
use App\File as FileModel;

public function index() 
{ 
   $files = FileModel::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(30);
}
```